# Is UIImage (UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions()) creation faster than init with PNG?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, png

Would using this class method and creating a solid color UIImage be faster than creating a png with a solid color?

```
+ (UIImage*) imageWithColor:(UIColor*)color size:(CGSize)size
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.0);
    UIBezierPath* rPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0., 0., size.width, size.height)];
    [color setFill];
    [rPath fill];
    UIImage* image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: There's only one good way to know for sure. Try both. Profile the code on a real device. Compare the results.

Comment: Why do you need a single color image? Depending on the need, a view with the background color set appropriately may suffice.

Comment: Another option would be to create a 1x1 pixel image and tile it.

Comment: @rmaddy I need a solid color image for a navigationcontroller bar and the only way to do that (without a serious hack and still be able to init with a rootviewcontroller) is to just init it with a solid image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hitting the disk and reading from cache (`imageNamed:`) is faster than Quartz.

```
-(void) testLoadVSCreate
{
    [self testBlock:^{
        [UIImage imageNamed:@"100x100.png"];
    } times:1000];

    [self testBlock:^{
        [[self class] imageWithColor:[UIColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(100, 100)];
    } times:1000];
}

-(void) testBlock:(void (^)(void)) block times:(NSUInteger)times {
    double a = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
    while (times--) block();
    double b = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();
    unsigned int m = ((b-a) * 1000.0f);
    NSLog(@"%d ms", m);
}
```

`imageNamed:` seems to be faster both on iPhone and the simulator.

```
2013-05-09 09:47:22.844 Graph[8032:c07] 7 ms
2013-05-09 09:47:22.948 Graph[8032:c07] 101 ms
```

Comment: But if it's a small image and it's cached, that's a one-time hit.

Comment: Sure, if you are going to run it a number of times versus reading from memory cache, then it will be slower. How many times, I don't know, testing is needed.

Comment: Agreed, hence my earlier comment (below the question) for the need to profile the code.

Comment: Did you run this on the simulator (on a machine with an HDD/SSD), or on a real device with flash memory?

Comment: @一二三 Got opposite results now. Initially I pasted that code on a debug configuration and got results all over the place. Also, even for something so simple, looking at it in the profiler is quite interesting to see how performance is tied to the implementation details. You never know until you profile!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it'd make a huge difference. I'd say loading from a PNG is faster. [This post](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/36591648724/designing-for-ios-graphics-performance) have a comparison.

The big advantage of creating the image via code is that you can easily change the color, not needing to generate another image resource and adding it to the project.